# Erro na execução da PROCEDURE

Tags: stored-procedures

Saúde e Paz para todos,
Trata-se do seguinte:
Tem uma tb_cadastro, para estudo de como povoar a tabela com datas (criada com MySQL), com os campos:

```
cliente_id  Primária    int(11) 
data_inicio     date 
dias_semanas    varchar(50)
```

Criei uma PROCEDURE com o nome adicionar_datas assim:

BEGIN

DECLARE var_data DATE;
DECLARE var_dia VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE contador INT DEFAULT 0;
SET var_data = data_inicio;
SET var_dia = DAYNAME(data_iniciO);
WHILE contador < intervalo DO
INSERT INTO tb_cadastro(data_inicio, dias_semanas) VALUES
(var_data, var_dia);
SET contador = contador + 1;
SET var_data = DATE_ADD(data_iniciO, INTERVAL CONTADOR DAY);
SET var_dia = DAYNAME(var_data);
END WHILE;

END

CALL adicionar_datas('2021-01-14',5)

Ao executar recebo a mensagem de erro:

Mensagens do MySQL : #1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'CALL adicionar_datas('2021-01-14',5)' na linha 19

Esperava que fosse povoar a minha tb_cadastro com cinco datas após 2021-01-14 com as respectivos dias_semanas.

Obrigado

Comment: Faltou você mostrar a definição dos parâmetros da procedure (CREATE PROCEDURE).

Comment: Você tem toda razão. Eu não guardei, nos meus estudos, o mais importante que são os "Parâmetros" quando da criação da Procedure. Desculpe!
Não sei se ajuda informar que em "Editar rotina", "Parâmetros" tem:

"Direção" = INT
"Nome" = data_inicio
"Tipo" = DATE